# NLog contains filter is not taking into effect

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nlog

I am trying to setup NLog for the first time, but I am unable to get filter working.

```
            var antiPOCOLogginRule = new LoggingRule("*");
            antiPOCOLogginRule.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter() { 
                Condition = "contains('${message}','POCO')",
                Action = FilterResult.IgnoreFinal
            });
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, logDebug);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Warn, LogLevel.Fatal, logEvent);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(antiPOCOLogginRule);
```

But the output still gives me this:

```
2021-11-04 09:09:07.8885|WARN|ReactiveUI.POCOObservableForProperty|The class KardexTerminal_PDA_WPF.Views.ReorderLogsView property Logs_ItemsControl is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
2021-11-04 09:09:07.9675|WARN|ReactiveUI.POCOObservableForProperty|The class KardexTerminal_PDA_WPF.Views.SerialInputView property TextBox_SerialNumber is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
2021-11-04 09:09:07.9953|WARN|ReactiveUI.POCOObservableForProperty|The class KardexTerminal_PDA_WPF.Views.SerialInputView property ProgressBar_ProccessingSerialNumber is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
2021-11-04 09:09:08.0058|WARN|ReactiveUI.POCOObservableForProperty|The class KardexTerminal_PDA_WPF.Views.SerialInputView property Border_LastMessage is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
2021-11-04 09:09:08.0271|WARN|ReactiveUI.POCOObservableForProperty|The class KardexTerminal_PDA_WPF.Views.SerialInputView property TextBlock_LastMessage is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
```

I must be missing something really obvious, but I am not sure what it is. (This is only filter I am trying to add, so nothing should interfere)

For completeness sage I am adding whole logging configuration.

I am using Splat logging, since I am using ReactiveUI for WPF.

```
        public static void Configure()
        {
            var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

            var antiPOCOLogginRule = new LoggingRule("*");
            antiPOCOLogginRule.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter() { 
                Condition = "contains('${message}','POCO')",
                Action = FilterResult.IgnoreFinal
            });

            var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") 
            { 
                FileName = "log.txt",  
                NetworkWrites = true, 
                OptimizeBufferReuse= true,  
                ArchiveAboveSize = 5000000,
                ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Date,
                MaxArchiveFiles = 5,
                ArchiveOldFileOnStartup = true,
                ConcurrentWrites = true
            };
            var logDebug = new NLog.Targets.DebuggerTarget("Debug");
            var logEvent = new NLog.Targets.EventLogTarget("EventLog") { OptimizeBufferReuse = true, Log = "Application"  };


            // Rules for mapping loggers to targets            
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, logDebug);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Warn, LogLevel.Fatal, logEvent);


            antiPOCOLogginRule.Targets.Add(logfile);
            antiPOCOLogginRule.Targets.Add(logDebug);
            antiPOCOLogginRule.Targets.Add(logEvent);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(antiPOCOLogginRule);

            // Apply config           
            NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;

            Locator.CurrentMutable.UseNLogWithWrappingFullLogger();
        }
```

EDIT----

From feedback of Rolf Kristensen I did remake my code to this:

```
  var antiPOCOLogginRule = new LoggingRule("*");
            antiPOCOLogginRule.EnableLoggingForLevels(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal);
            antiPOCOLogginRule.Filters.Add(new WhenMethodFilter(log => log.Message.Contains("POCO") ? FilterResult.IgnoreFinal : FilterResult.Neutral));


            antiPOCOLogginRule.Targets.Add(logfile);
            antiPOCOLogginRule.Targets.Add(logDebug);
            antiPOCOLogginRule.Targets.Add(logEvent);

            // Rules for mapping loggers to targets       
            config.LoggingRules.Add(antiPOCOLogginRule);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, logDebug);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Warn, LogLevel.Fatal, logEvent);
```

But the rule still wont apply for some reason...

Comment: Your 3 calls to `config.AddRule` ensures that all loggers write directly to their targets without regard of any filtering applied for `antiPOCOLogginRule`.

Comment: Oof, I am not really sure how to fix that, could you direct me please a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Think you are very close:

```
        var antiPOCOLogginRule = new LoggingRule() { FilterDefaultAction = FilterResult.Neutral };
        antiPOCOLogginRule.LoggerNamePattern = "*";
        antiPOCOLogginRule.EnableLoggingForLevels(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal);
        antiPOCOLogginRule.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter()
        {
            Condition = "contains('${message}','POCO')",
            Action = FilterResult.IgnoreFinal
        });
        antiPOCOLogginRule.Targets.Add(new NLog.Targets.NullTarget());  // Dynamic filters requires a target

        // Rules for mapping loggers to targets
        config.LoggingRules.Add(antiPOCOLogginRule); // First filter final
        config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logDebug);
        config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);
        config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Warn, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logEvent);
```

The following things has been updated for `antiPOCOLogginRule`:

- Add `EnableLoggingForLevels` so it will actually match loglevels
- Add `LoggerNamePattern` so it will actually match loggers
- Add `NullTarget` since NLog fails to check dynamic filters when no target.

P.S. Instead of `ConditionBasedFilter` then you could also use `WhenMethodFilter` like this:

```
antiPOCOLogginRule.Filters.Add(new WhenMethodFilter(log => log.FormattedMessage.Contains("POCO") ? FilterResult.IgnoreFinal : FilterResult.Neutral) { Action = FilterResult.IgnoreFinal });
```

Comment: Notice you can also use `WhenMethodFilter` with `LogEventInfo.FormattedMessage` instead of `ConditionBasedFilter`.

Comment: Hello, I am not really sure what is wrong. Please check edited OP, I did do things you suggested, but the rule still wont apply...

Comment: @TomášFilip Yes discovered that `LoggingRule(string ruleName)`-constructor doesn't assign LoggerNamePattern. Have updated the answer.